# AWS API Gateway REST DELETE method call from android app working fine in emulator but not working from device?

Tags: android, rest, amazon-web-services

I am calling AWS API Gateway REST service from my android app through AsyncTask. All method working fine both in emulator and device. But when I call delete then in emulator working fine but from device it is giving an error that

```
 java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at $Proxy1.userDelete(Native Method)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at com.example.nmsapp.CustomUserAdapter$DeleteUsers.doInBackground(CustomUserAdapter.java:130)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at com.example.nmsapp.CustomUserAdapter$DeleteUsers.doInBackground(CustomUserAdapter.java:107)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: DELETE does not support writing
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.initHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:86)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.writeContentToConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:128)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:65)
09-28 15:32:03.133  12335-12824/com.example.nmsapp W/System.err﹕ at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.invoke(ApiClientHandler.java:91)
```

Android Menifest permission are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: would you please share you api definition (mask sensitive content if necessary)? is it a delete method + content body?

Comment: API is working fine using POSTMAN but not working with device

Comment: please make sure your computer  and your device are on same network. And make sure nor proxy settings on your device

Comment: POSTMAN != Android device. The SDK uses HttpURLConnection and thus can't do DELETE with content body. So how is you API defined?

Comment: when I use emulator it is working fine but if this app used from an device then it gives "java.net.ProtocolException: DELETE does not support writing" error

Comment: is DELETE method support request body? When I have write DELETE method using query parameter then it is working fine but if DELETE method is implemented using request body then it is not working.

Comment: I have the same problem, but not from Android. You can test it out even with CURL or Chrome Poster.   Delete map to Delete doesn't work with the AWS URL.   However, if you use the "Test" simulator or just simply try mapping a POST to a DELETE, it will work.   Probably some bugs in API-gateway

Answer (score 1):

DELETE with body can lead to unexpected behavior. Per HTTP/1.1 RFC2616, this is neither allowed not disallowed. However, depending on which HTTP library you use, the behavior may vary. As for the generated API Gateway client, its uses HttpURLConnection as recommended by Android. Nevertheless, the implementation of HttpURLConnection is platform dependent. Priory to API level 19, it's close to Java's standard implementation by Sun, where ProtocolException will be thrown on DELETE with body. Since API level 19, Android switches to OkHttp which permits such behavior (see https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/605). This should explain why it works on some place but not the other. In summary, I suggest you avoid defining an API which does DELETE with body.